# remove array on duplicate value

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I need help. I want to remove array on array list when there is duplicate value. 
I have this array

```
Array
(
[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [count] => 2
                [price] => 1000
                [total] => 2000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [count] => 0
                [price] => 124
                [total] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [count] => 0
                [price] => 1000
                [total] => 0
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [count] => 0
                [price] => 2345
                [total] => 0
            )

    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [count] => 0
                [price] => 1000
                [total] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [count] => 1
                [price] => 124
                [total] => 124
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [count] => 0
                [price] => 1000
                [total] => 0
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [count] => 0
                [price] => 2345
                [total] => 0
            )

    )
)
```

As you may notice that there are duplication value on price key. But I only want to remove an array if the the count is equal to 0. But if the duplicate price has no value on count. It only remove one duplicate array. My expected output will be like this.

```
Array
(
[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [count] => 2
                [price] => 1000
                [total] => 2000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [count] => 0
                [price] => 124
                [total] => 0
            )


        [2] => Array
            (
                [count] => 0
                [price] => 2345
                [total] => 0
            )

    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [count] => 0
                [price] => 1000
                [total] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [count] => 1
                [price] => 124
                [total] => 124
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [count] => 0
                [price] => 2345
                [total] => 0
            )

    )
)
```

Please help thanks.